# Failed to deploy application - ruby on aws eb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I try to deploy my ruby app in eb cli on aws by following commands,

> eb init,
>
> eb create staging3 -db.engine postgres

I get following error

```
2019-01-25 20:51:40    ERROR   [Instance: i-058d307792dcfcce7] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...b:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace). 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2019-01-25 20:51:41    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2019-01-25 20:51:41    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-058d307792dcfcce7'. Aborting the operation.
2019-01-25 20:51:41    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

Logs

```
+ '[' false == true ']'
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp
  `/home/webapp` is not a directory.
  Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/webapp' as your home directory temporarily.
  DEPRECATION WARNING: `config.static_cache_control` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
  Please use
  `config.public_file_server.headers = { 'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=2592000' }`
  instead.
   (called from block in <top (required)> at /var/app/ondeck/config/environments/production.rb:28)
  intializing git
  sh: git: command not found
  sh: line 0: cd: /home/webapp: No such file or directory
  rake aborted!
  SyntaxError: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.2.1/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:5: syntax error, une
xpected '{', expecting end
  ...ion only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_tim...
  ...                              ^
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.2.1/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '}', 
expecting end
  ..."devise.skip_timeout"] = true }
  ...                              ^
  /var/app/ondeck/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

[Detailed log file](http://pasted.co/d68d0f9a)
tried in heroku but works well.

Comment: what is ruby version on your local system? looks like <2.5. Your need to use ruby version which this devise gem supports. For example 2.4.x. Or upgrade devise gem to newer

Comment: I have tried ruby version 2.3 on aws. Now I have http://pasted.co/f1cafb69

Comment: do ls -la /var/app/current Is the app deployed?

Comment: I dont understand, The above error fixed by adding `database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %> `. Now I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380863/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git` command doesn't appear to be installed on your instance as seen in the log output:

```
intializing git
sh: git: command not found
```

I think you should be able to get it installed by adding the following to your `.ebextensions/ruby.config` file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

Comment: In aws? How to do it?

Comment: @FunMedia, your problem is addressed [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4736). Update your version of `devise` in your Gemfile to 4.4.0

Comment: I am having issue with this line `/home/webapp` is not a directory `. Is that fixed?