# password authentication failed for user "ebroot" elastic beanstalk

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy ruby app to aws using elastic beanstalk. I cd into repo, then `git init`, `git add --all`, `git commit -am "update"`, `eb init`, `eb create staging3 -db.engine postgres`, fixed some error, then `eb deploy`. Now I get

> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ebroot"

My database.yml

```
    adapter: postgresql  
    host: localhost   
    username: ggg   
    database: rtt  


production:  
  adapter: postgresql  
  encoding: utf8  
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>  
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>  
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>  
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>  
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

My log http://pasted.co/6590f3ae

I am noob, Is this password has any connection with the password I created when database creation and migration **locally**.

Comment: you app is not deployed. provide full eb-activity.log when it started deploying.

Comment: Full log http://pasted.co/08beda92

Comment: looks strange. the error:   sh: line 0: cd: /home/webapp: No such file or directory
it says that the instance doesn't have webapp home dir. did you deleted it? try to terminate the instance. aws eb will create new one.

Comment: What is webapp home dir, I don't have webapp folder in my project, You mean terminate environment?

Comment: no, only delete the screwed up instance. it is in EC2. webapp it is a user. which used to run you app, it has a home dir. But not in your case. it is deleted.

Comment: I terminated instance in ec2. Now what to do?

Comment: wait, when new one up and try to redeploy

Comment: Still same http://pasted.co/8958562c

Comment: ebroot is this user for postgres?

Comment: when I issue eb init, I enter for default, which was ebroot

Comment: go to RDS end check user and password is the same

Comment: How to do it?  don't know

Comment: Amazon RDS, it is in console next to the EB. find postgres instance and check it's config. ensure RDS_USERNAME equals user and RDS_PASSWORD equals password there. RDS_USERNAME and RDS_PASSWORD you can find in EB Configuration -> Software

Comment: I can't find RDS_USERNAME and RDS_PASSWORD in https://i.postimg.cc/SQVGcLMJ/Screenshot-from-2019-01-27-00-20-22.png  Also how to check config of instance

Comment: then you need to add all these ENV vars there

Comment: Still same error :( I added username and password only. What is database host and port?

Comment: database: ebdb, default port: 5432 (not sure, don't use it)

Comment: So no way to solve, anyway thanks for support

Comment: a lot of ways :) Try to build a new ENV w/o RDS, create RDS manually and use needed username and password. create EB env/app with ENV vars. it should work.

Comment: I can't connect to host via browser https://i.postimg.cc/bNMSbPQF/Screenshot-from-2019-01-27-01-48-13.png  testinstance.c0pjwhabjrgu.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com Also what is the eb create command to biuld env without RDS

Comment: If I deployed with ruby 2.2 puma, application get deployed but with a warning status.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>` to `password: "<%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>"` fixes the problem. Can you please tell me why this is like this?